# MongoDB querying to with changing values for key

Tags: mongodb

Im trying to get back into Mongodb and Ive come across something that I cant figure out. 
I have this data structure

```
> db.ratings.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("55881e43424cbb1817137b33"),
        "e_id" : ObjectId("5565e106cd7a763b2732ad7c"),
        "type" : "like",
        "time" : 1434984003156,
        "u_id" : ObjectId("55817c072e48b4b60cf366a7")
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("55893be1e6a796c0198e65d3"),
        "e_id" : ObjectId("5565e106cd7a763b2732ad7c"),
        "type" : "dislike",
        "time" : 1435057121808,
        "u_id" : ObjectId("55817c072e48b4b60cf366a7")
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("55893c21e6a796c0198e65d4"),
        "e_id" : ObjectId("5565e106cd7a763b2732ad7c"),
        "type" : "null",
        "time" : 1435057185089,
        "u_id" : ObjectId("55817c072e48b4b60cf366a7")
}
```

What I want to be able to do is count the documents that have either a like or dislike leaving the "null" out of the count. So I should have a count of 2. I tried to go about it like this whereby I set the query to both fields:

```
 db.ratings.find({e_id: ObjectId("5565e106cd7a763b2732ad7c")}, {type: "like", type: "dislike"})
```

But this just prints out all three documents. Is there any reason? 
If its glaringly obvious im sorry pulling out my hair at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following **[`db.collection.count()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/)** method which returns the count of documents that would match a **[`find()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find)** query:

```
db.ratings.count({
    "e_id": ObjectId("5565e106cd7a763b2732ad7c"), 
    type: {
        "$in": ["like", "dislike"]
    }
})
```

The **`db.collection.count()`** method is equivalent to the **`db.collection.find(query).count()`** construct. Your query selection criteria above can be interpreted as:

Get me the count of all documents which have the `e_id` field values as `ObjectId("5565e106cd7a763b2732ad7c")` **AND** the `type` field which has either value "like" or "dislike", as depicted by the **[`$in`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)** operator that selects the documents where the value of a field equals any value in the specified array.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>  db.ratings.find({e_id: ObjectId("5565e106cd7a763b2732ad7c")},
>                  {type: "like", type: "dislike"})
> ```
>
> But this just prints out all three
>   documents. Is there any reason?  If its glaringly obvious im sorry
>   pulling out my hair at the moment.

The second argument here is the *projection* used by the [`find` method](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db-collection-find) . It specifies fields that should be included -- regardless of their value. Normally, you specify a boolean value of `1` or `true` to include the field. Obviously, MongoDB accepts other values as true.

---

If you only need to *count* documents, you should issue a [`count` command](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/count/):

```
> db.runCommand({count: 'collection',
               query: { "e_id" : ObjectId("5565e106cd7a763b2732ad7c"),
                        type: { $in: ["like", "dislike"]}}
})
{ "n" : 2, "ok" : 1 }
```

Please note the Mongo Shell provides the [`count` helper](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.count/#cursor.count) for that:

```
> db.collection.find({ "e_id" : ObjectId("5565e106cd7a763b2732ad7c"),
                       type: { $in: ["like", "dislike"]}}).count()
2
```

That being said, to quote the documentation, using the `count` command *"can result in an inaccurate count if orphaned documents exist or if a chunk migration is in progress."* To avoid that, you might prefer using the aggregation framework:

```
> db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { "e_id" : ObjectId("5565e106cd7a763b2732ad7c"),
              type: { $in: ["like", "dislike"]}}},
  { $group: { _id: null, n: { $sum: 1 }}}
])
{ "_id" : null, "n" : 2 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This query should solve your problem

```
db.ratings.find({$or : [{"type": "like"}, {"type": "dislike"}]}).count()
```